# How change permission public_profile from Standard access to Advanced access when application disabled

Tags: authentication

My app integrate Login Facebook, login facebook need permission: public_profile (Advanced access). But my app was disabled by Facebook because screencast not display app id. I don't know Login Facebook need permission public_profile (Advanced access). After that, I remove all permissions, and remove public_profile (Advanced access) to Standard access. And Login Facebook flow not work, it display need public_profile (Advanced access) to work.

But when app was disabled, I can not change public profile from Standard access to Advanced access. I try many time, but not change.

I make request Appeals page to help, but nothing help.
What can I do to do re-enable my application, or can change public_profile to Advanced access to complete Login Facebook flow?

I try make request Facebook Developer Appeals page.